# Delphi Component Creation.. Getting Beyond First Base

Tags: delphi, components, creation

I've used VBto as a starting point plus a lot of study of Delphi 6 User's Guide. I can make my new component compile, but I can't figure a way to get it to display so I can finish debugging it. And 50 years of programming experience isn't helping. Here are the guts of my component:

```
type 

 TChangeEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; v: String) of object;
 TTxtSpnr = class(TWinControl)
   Lbl: TLabel;
   Txt: TEdit;
   Scrll:   TScrollBar;
 private
   FonChange: TChangeEvent;
   busy, tweaked: Boolean;
   NewValue: String;
 protected
   procedure Changed(v: String); dynamic;
   property onChange: TChangeEvent read FonChange write FOnChange;
   procedure ScrllChange(Sender: TObject);
   procedure ScrllScroll(Sender: TObject; ScrollCode: TScrollCode; var ScrollPos: Integer);
   procedure TxtEnter(Sender: TObject);
   procedure TxtKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: WORD; Shift: TShiftState);
   procedure TxtExit(Sender: TObject);
   procedure Txt_Validate(var Cancel: Boolean);
 public
   function GetCaption(): String;
   procedure SetCaption(New_Caption: String);
   function GetMax(): Smallint;
   procedure SetMax(New_Max: Smallint);
   function MaxOf(a: Double; B: Longint): OleVariant;
   function MinOf(a: OleVariant; B: Longint): OleVariant;
   function GetMin(): Smallint;
   procedure SetMin(New_Min: Smallint);
   function GetText(): String;
   procedure SetText(New_Text: String);
   constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
   destructor Destroy; override;
 published
   property Caption: String read GetCaption write SetCaption;
   property Enabled: Boolean read GetEnabled write SetEnabled;
   property Max: Smallint read GetMax write SetMax;
   property Min: Smallint read GetMin write SetMin;
   property Text: String read GetText write SetText;
 end;
var 
 TxtSpnr: TTxtSpnr;
implementation 

uses Math; 
{$R *.dfm} 

procedure TTxtSpnr.Changed(V: String); begin 

 if assigned(FonChange) then FonChange(self,V);
end; 

constructor TTxtSpnr.Create(AOwner: TComponent); begin 

 inherited Create(AOwner);
 Lbl := TLabel.Create(Self);
 with Lbl do begin
   Parent := Self;
 end;
 Txt := TEdit.Create(Self);
 with Txt do begin
   Parent := Self;
 end;
 Scrll := TScrollBar(Self);
 with Scrll do begin
   Parent := Self;
 end;
end;
```

and here's the test driver:

```
type 

 TForm1 = class(TForm)
   FTxtSpnr: TTxtSpnr;
   procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 private
   { Private declarations }
 public
   { Public declarations }
 end;
var 

 Form1: TForm1;
implementation 

{$R *.dfm} 

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); begin 

 FTxtSpnr := TTxtSpnr.create(Self);
 with FTxtSpnr do begin
   Left:=10;
   Top:=10;
   Visible:=true;
   Show;
 end;
end;
```

But it doesn't compile and says, in the constructor, "An object can't be its own parent". Take out the Parent settings, it compiles but doesn't display the components. What am I missing?

Comment: Any particular reason why you use `TWinControl` and not the `TCustomControl`, as you normally use? Also, I hope `Scrll` is not to be used as the control's vertical or horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: This is one of the reasons to avoid using "with". With in your code for the label refers to itself, and not your component as you intended.

Answer (score 4):

First,

```
Scrll := TScrollBar(Self);
```

should of course read

```
Scrll := TScrollBar.Create(Self);
```

Second,

```
FTxtSpnr := TTxtSpnr.create(Self);
with FTxtSpnr do begin
  Left:=10;
  Top:=10;
  Visible:=true;
  Show;
end;
```

should be

```
FTxtSpnr := TTxtSpnr.create(Self);
with FTxtSpnr do
begin
  Parent := Self;
  Left := 10;
  Top := 10;
end;
```

You forgot to set the parent.

Also, the global variable

```
var 
  TxtSpnr: TTxtSpnr;
```

looks dangerous. If you don't know exactly why you added those two lines, you should probably remove them.